# Building webrtc library

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to build webrtc android demo application. I was following README applied by the project. First thing was mentioned about gclient but when i tried to run it "no external or internal command". Then i got this [link](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/) according to the this link i cloned the depot_tool repository but when at the step when i try to run gclient i got this

[image]

So after hours of trying i am not able to run it. if any one has experience with this [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) library please provide some help. Any guidance? Any Hlep will be appreciated

Comment: i think i need to switch linux to build that app? is it right?

Comment: It is possible to build on windows, but there are additional steps. I have been successful in building it in linux.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent what method is there to build it on windows. can you please share ?

Answer (score 0):

I heard few things were changed from svn to GIT. We tried building webRTC to windows7 using visual studio. See if you can use any parts on this.

1. Get depot_tools software and extract to a location (set this path in environment variable).
2. cd to depot_tools directory and hit 'gclient' (this should take sometime)
3. Install python 2.7 and put it path.
4. create a folder of your choice for webRTC and open command prompt there.
5. Now hit, gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
6. then, gclient sync.
7. Then set GYP_GENERATORS=msvs environment variable (use ninja if you want that).
8. Also set msvs_version=2012 (depending on your visual studio version)
9. now run, gclient runhooks --force

This should generate solutions files for your folder. fireup the libjingle/webrtc.sln files and start building it. I'm not sure if it builds as is. But we had hicupps with that.

See this link on [WebRTC native development](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development/prerequisite-sw) if you haven't already. From my personal experience building this  tricky job initially.

Also note that links might be deprecated as they moved to git, don't know if they are still maintaining it.

Answer (score 0):

How to compile WEBRTC On ubuntu

download script and run:
https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/build/install-build-deps.sh

```
./build/install-build-deps.sh  --no-chromeos-fonts
```

Now download depot tools

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

Put it in Path

```
$ export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

Define your settings:

```
export GYP_DEFINES="target_arch=x64 host_arch=x64 build_with_chromium=0 use_openssl=0 use_gtk=0 use_x11=0 include_examples=0 include_tests=1 fastbuild=1 remove_webcore_debug_symbols=1 include_pulse_audio=0 include_internal_video_render=0 clang=1 "
```

make file to download the source

```
mkdir webrtc-checkout
cd webrtc-checkout
```

I chose branch 50 you can change it

```
gclient config https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git@branch-heads/50 --name=src
gclient sync --force --with_branch_heads 
gclient sync --force --with_branch_heads --nohooks 

cd src

git checkout branch-heads/50

gclient runhooks 
ninja -C ./out/Release
```

Collect your LIB & Include file to use it in your project

```
mkdir ../lib/
find  ./ -name "*.o" -and -not -name do_not_use -and -not -name protoc -and -not -name genperf -exec ar crs ../lib/libwebrtc.a {} +
mkdir ../include
find ./ -name *.h -exec cp --parents '{}' ../include ';'
```